# WSS 3.0 Wiki export

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, sharepoint-services

We have a WSS 3.0 server with a lot of wiki pages created which need to be moved over to MediaWiki.

Are there any tools that can be used to automate this process?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found http://churchofchai.blogspot.com/2007/10/sharepoint-to-mediawiki.html which might be of some use.